# Python parsing list of dict

Tags: python-3.x

My code output is:

`eval = [{'ComplianceResourceType': 'AWS::CodeBuild::Project', 'ComplianceResourceId': 'hello-cb', 'ComplianceType': 'COMPLIANT', 'OrderingTimestamp': '2020-04-09T03:09:08.624Z'}, {'ComplianceResourceType': 'AWS::CodeBuild::Project', 'ComplianceResourceId': 'douglas-codebuild-deploy', 'ComplianceType': 'NON_COMPLIANT', 'OrderingTimestamp': '2020-04-09T03:09:08.624Z'}, {'ComplianceResourceType': 'AWS::CodeBuild::Project', 'ComplianceResourceId': 'douglas-codebuild-test', 'ComplianceType': 'NON_COMPLIANT', 'OrderingTimestamp': '2020-04-09T03:09:08.624Z'}]`

I would like to use boto3 for Config to loop through this list of dict and get the values to input in this API call.

`

```
config = boto3.client("config")
    config.put_evaluations(
        Evaluations=[
            {
                "ComplianceResourceType":' ',
                "ComplianceResourceId": ' ',
                "ComplianceType": ' ',
                "OrderingTimestamp":' '        
            }
        ]
    )
```

`

Could someone assist me in this?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be `config.put_evaluations(Evaluations=eval)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Solution:

```
eval = [{'ComplianceResourceType': 'AWS::CodeBuild::Project', 'ComplianceResourceId': 'hello-cb', 'ComplianceType': 'COMPLIANT', 'OrderingTimestamp': '2020-04-09T03:09:08.624Z'}, {'ComplianceResourceType': 'AWS::CodeBuild::Project', 'ComplianceResourceId': 'douglas-codebuild-deploy', 'ComplianceType': 'NON_COMPLIANT', 'OrderingTimestamp': '2020-04-09T03:09:08.624Z'}, {'ComplianceResourceType': 'AWS::CodeBuild::Project', 'ComplianceResourceId': 'douglas-codebuild-test', 'ComplianceType': 'NON_COMPLIANT', 'OrderingTimestamp': '2020-04-09T03:09:08.624Z'}]


for i in eval:
    config = boto3.client("config")
    config.put_evaluations(Evaluations=[i])
```

Hope it may helps you.